# How to use Python ipaddress module

Tags: python-3.x

```
import ipaddress
my_internal = [ipaddress.ip_network('10.0.0.0/8'),
               ipaddress.ip_network('12.0.0.0/8')]
my_sg = [ipaddress.ip_network('10.20.0.0/16'),
         ipaddress.ip_network('123.168.0.0/16')]
not_internal_cidrs=[]


for security_group_entry in my_sg:
   for my_subnets in my_internal:
        if security_group_entry.overlaps(my_subnets):
            pass
        else:
            not_internal_cidrs.append(security_group_entry)

not_internal_cidrs = list(dict.fromkeys(not_internal_cidrs))
print(*not_internal_cidrs, sep='\n')
```

it still shows 10.20.0.0/16 as being not part of 10.0.0.0/8

Comment: It's added because it was tested against `12.0.0.0/8`. You can manually test to check that both `my_internal[0].overlaps(my_sg[0])` and `my_sg[0].overlaps(my_internal[0])` are `True`.

Comment: Thanks Chris..let me check